# Solspace User - not accepting new members: Error mbr_addon_builder

Tags: cartthrob, module, upgrade, solspace-user

I am running EE 2.7.1 and User 3.4.0

When a new member resisters the redirect does not work just loads a blank page and the membership does not process..

So I updated the Solspace User to 3.4.5 and ran the module update and get this error: 
Unable to load the requested class: mbr_addon_builder

The registration seems to be working now after the User upgrade, but I can't run module updates anymore without getting that error

Any assistance would be great!!

UPDATE: Looks like it may be related not to CartThrob.  That file is in the CT Permissions library folder.  Tried to remove it but still getting the error

So I tried to update Cart Throb Permission Manager 2.3.3 and then I get the same error and cannot even log into the control panel

Comment: This error only appears in the CP when visiting the Modules section? There is no class called `mbr_addon_builder` in Solspace User. Have you made sure you're using the latest version of CartThrob (not just CartThrob Permission Manager)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it was a CT issue, an upgrade fixed the issue